# VisualSVN checkout doesn't work

Tags: svn, visualsvn-server, post-commit, svn-hooks

I wanted to checkout when there is a commit to a particular path in svn.
In VisualSVN -> Properties -> Post-Commit hook:

```
"D:\Program Files\VisualSVN Server\bin\svn.exe" checkout https://***.****.***/svn/Mobile/Node/trunk C:\MyPath
```

Then I went and did a commit, but I don't see any checkouts happened.
When I execute the post-commit script manually it checks out to that path.

I am getting error as "- The certificate is not issued by a trusted authority. Use the fingerprint to validate the certificate manually! Certificate information:"

How can I resolve it?

Comment: I am getting error as "- The certificate is not issued by a trusted authority. Use the
   fingerprint to validate the certificate manually!
Certificate information:"

Answer (score 0):

Common hook troubleshooting steps are described at the [official Subversion FAQ: "Why aren't my repository hooks working?"](http://subversion.apache.org/faq.html#hook-debugging).

The particular issue you've encountered is the side-effect of these facts:

1. You run VisualSVN Server with a self-signed certificate which is not trusted in your environment. Normally, you must manually accept such certificate on client-side.
2. Hooks are executed under the account which runs VisualSVN Server's service.
3. VisualSVN Server runs under [`Network Service` account](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684272%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), by default. As far as I guess your VisualSVN Server instance runs under `Network Service` account, so you have to login under Network Service, run `svn.exe` against the repository and permanently accept the certificate. You can't logon under `Network Service` account as you usually logon under your user account but there is a smart trick which can help.

So there is 1 correct solution to this and 2 workarounds:

- SOLUTION: Run VisualSVN Server with a trusted signed server certificate. You can obtain one from a certificate authority (i.e. buy the certificate) or [sign server's certificate with Active Directory Certificate Services installed in your organization](http://www.visualsvn.com/support/topic/00035/).
- WORKAROUND1: [Configure VisualSVN Server to run under a custom dedicated user account](http://www.visualsvn.com/support/topic/00024/), login to Windows under this account, run `svn.exe` against the repository and permanently accept the untrusted certificate.
- WORKAROUND2: Keep VisualSVN Server running under `Network Service` and use `psexec` tool to accept the certificate under `Network Service` account:

  You can use the [Sysinternals's PsExec utility](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896649) to run `svn.exe` under the `Network Service` and accept the certificate manually. Execute the following command line to run the command prompt under the `Network Service` account (adjust the command line if you run the service under other account):

  `psexec -u "nt authority\network service" cmd.exe`

  Then permanently accept the certificate using the `svn.exe`. Run the following command and permanently accept the certificate when prompted:

  `svn info <URL-to-repository>`